# Excel2Latex Formatting Issue

Tags: tables, formatting, excel2latex

I am struggling with the formatting of a table I created using the Excel2Latex macro. Below you can see a screenshot of the Excel output:

[image]

Using the Excel2Latex macro, the table in Latex looks like this:

[image]

Therefore, my problem is that in the areas I marked with red circles I rotated the text by 90 degrees and in Excel, I wrote the text in merged cells. However, in Latex the text is only in the first cell of the in Excel vertically merged cells causing the respective Latex first rows to increase a lot. Can you by any chance help me to vertically merge these cells in Latex? Additionally, I would like to center the text over the height of the vertically merged cells. I also attached my code.

Thanks so much for your help, highly appreciated!

Best,
Tim

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrlccclccclcccrrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Statistics}} &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Huge}} &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Large}} &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Medium}} &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Small }} \\
\cmidrule{1-3}\cmidrule{5-7}\cmidrule{9-11}\cmidrule{13-15}\cmidrule{17-19}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{N}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Mu}} &       & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Test }} & \textbf{Stat.} & \textbf{Sig.} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Test }} & \textbf{Stat.} & \textbf{Sig.} &       & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Test }} & \textbf{Stat.} & \textbf{Sig.} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Test }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Stat.}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Sig.}} \\
\cmidrule{1-3}\cmidrule{5-11}\cmidrule{13-15}\cmidrule{17-19}    
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Huge}\end{sideways}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{\begin{sideways}13.500\end{sideways}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{\begin{sideways}19,1\%\end{sideways}}} &       &       &       &       &       & Diff. & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & Diff. & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Diff.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.000,00} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{***} \\
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & T     & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & T     & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{T} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.000,00} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{***} \\
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & MWU   & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & MWU   & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{MWU} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.000,00} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{***} \\
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & KS    & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & KS    & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{KS } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.000,00} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{***} \\
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & AD    & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & AD    & 1.000,00 & ***   &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{AD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.000,00} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{***} \\

    \bottomrule
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply forgot that `\multirow` has 3 arguments: the number of lines it must  emcompass, its width  and its contents.

I took the opportunity to simplify the code, and I propose an alternative layout which doesn't require `landscape` mode: I use only one `test` column, whereas it is repeated thrice in the code you posted. Of course, maybe this is not relevant for your actual code. Also maybe the actual code  would  require the `S` column type (from `siunitx`) for a nice alignment for the numeric columns.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array, multirow, rotating, makecell, caption, booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrc*{8}{lc}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Statistics}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Huge}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Large}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Medium}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Small }} \\
      \cmidrule{1-3}\cmidrule{5-7}\cmidrule{9-11}\cmidrule{13-15}\cmidrule{17-19}%
        & \thead{N} & \thead{Mu} & & \thead{Test } & \thead{Stat.} & \thead{Sig.} & & \thead{Test } & \thead{Stat.} & \thead{Sig.} & & \thead{Test } & \thead{Stat.} & \thead{Sig.} & & \thead{Test} & \thead{Stat.} & \thead{Sig.} \\
      \cmidrule{1-3}\cmidrule{5-7}\cmidrule{9-11}\cmidrule{13-15}\cmidrule{17-19}%
      \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Huge}\end{sideways}}
      & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{sideways}13.500\end{sideways}}
      & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{sideways}19,1\%\end{sideways}}
      & & & & & & Diff. & 1.000,00 & *** & & Diff. & 1.000,00 & *** & &Diff. & 1.000,00 & *** \\
        & & & & & & & & T & 1.000,00 & *** & & T & 1.000,00 & *** & & T & 1.000,00 & *** \\
        & & & & & & & & MWU & 1.000,00 & *** & & MWU & 1.000,00 & *** & & MWU & 1.000,00 & *** \\
        & & & & & & & & KS & 1.000,00 & *** & & KS & 1.000,00 & *** & & KS & 1.000,00 & *** \\
        & & & & & & & & AD & 1.000,00 & *** & & AD & 1.000,00 & *** & & AD & 1.000,00 & *** \\
      \bottomrule
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
  \end{table}%
  %
\end{landscape}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt}
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabular}{rrrc>{\bfseries}r*{4}{ccl}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Statistics}} & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Huge}} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Large}} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Medium}} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Small }}
    \\
    \cmidrule{1-3}\cmidrule{7-8}\cmidrule{10-11}\cmidrule{13-14}\cmidrule{16-17}%%\cmidrule{9-11}\cmidrule{13-15}%\cmidrule{17-19}%
      & \thead{N} & \thead{Mu} & & \thead{Test } & & \thead{Stat.} & \thead{Sig.} & & \thead{Stat.} & \thead{Sig.} & & \thead{Stat.} & \thead{Sig.} & & \thead{Stat.} & \thead{Sig.} \\
    \cmidrule{1-3}\cmidrule{5-5}\cmidrule{7-8}\cmidrule{10-11}\cmidrule{13-14}\cmidrule{16-17}%
    \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Huge}\end{sideways}}
    & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{sideways}13.500\end{sideways}}
    & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{sideways}19,1\%\end{sideways}}
    & & Diff. & & & & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** \\
      & & & & T & & & & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** \\
      & & & & MWU & & & & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** \\
      & & & & KS & & & & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** \\
      & & & & AD & & & & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** & & 1.000,00 & *** \\
    \bottomrule
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Less wide layout (proposal):
[image]